# Does tipping people do anything?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In Parfum Palace, there is a wandering minstrel who will sing a little song.  You then have the option of tipping him.  The same thing happened with the man who was telling me about how the Battle Chateau works.  Is there any point to tipping people?

Comment: I gave him 100 and he just thanked me (damn I was expecting my master ball!)

Comment: I have been tipping everyone who has asked me so far 1000 and so far nothing has happened, however i am going to keep tipping to see if it has any effect.

Comment: According do some, it raises the chance of finding a shiny pokemon. Not sure if it's true, but I'm gonna keep giving whoever asks 1000, just in case it's true.

Comment: Well, one thing it does is that it makes them give you a really nice compliment :) other than that, I kinda think that Nintendo wouldn't add the functionality if it didn't do a thing. Maybe it gives you a good "ending", maybe a trader will give you better items/prices, or maybe they'll come back to help you out in a crucial battle sometime. Who knows?

Comment: @Vilde where did you hear about it raising the shiny encounter? Just curious because I haven't heard anything regarding that and I was hoping to find out if it was true or not.

Comment: Reading the title I thought this was some how related to "cow tipping." Now I am disappoint.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know, the tips only contribute to a medal in PGL (Pokemon Global Link, if you sync'd your game with your Pokemon Global Link account):

[image]

And when you click on the link...

[image]

I don't know the exact threshold to get the medal nor I know if there are any more effects, but currently, I don't think there are any effects besides getting the badge.