# Are there really small secret methods of raising one's chance of encountering a shiny?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So recently a friend of mine told me that you could boost your chance of getting a shiny by giving a high tip when going to the restaurant or by taking pictures everywhere you can.

Is this actually true? And if yes, by just how much does it increase the chance?

I know about the *Chaining* and *Breeding* methods that were discussed in multiple questions on *Arqade*, but are there some other secret methods?

Comment: Possible dupe:http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134343/does-tipping-people-do-anything

Comment: My bad, I misread your question. But the link I posted might help a little with yours. It asks about the tipping part, at least.

Comment: If they're secret, how would we know about them?  (Keep in mind that the 3DS hasn't been hacked yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently unknown what tipping does, and taking photos gives you items, but doesn't affect the shiny rate. The only known ways to increase the shiny chance are:

- Breeding with a pokemon from a different region. (The Masuda method)
- Chaining via the PokeRadar.
- Chain fishing
- Obtaining the "Shiny Charm", which is a key item obtained by catching one of every non-event pokemon.

Sources: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Photo#Pok.C3.A9mon_X_and_Y (photos)
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon#Generation_VI (shiny methods)

Answer (score -1):

Tipping in the restaurants is very unlikely to do anything. If you want an "easy" way of getting a shiny, get a foreign (foreign as in not from the country your game is from) Ditto and breed pokemon.